# PHP: Changing status of users from waiting to accepted as a batch

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a system designed in cakephp. Users who apply have a default status of waiting.

How do I change all users from the status of waiting to accepted in a single operation?

Comment: At what point do you want to set their status to "accepted"? As soon as possible or after something happens? Need more info here

Comment: They have a default status of waiting, when they have been accepted their status should change to accepted. When they log on their status should tell them they have been accepted not the waiting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->User->updateAll(                    // UPDATE users
    array('User.status' => "'accepted'"),  // SET status='accepted'
    $conditions                            // WHERE ... (your conditions)
);
```

See [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions)